# WPF - binding integer list to combobox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, binding, prism

I want to bind a List to a WPF combobox in xaml. Wondering what is the simplest way to do it.

(The reason behind is I want to  maintain the years as integer rather than doing the type conversion from string to int. I get a list of years(2009,2010,2011) from the DB and want to be able to bind this to the combo and get the selected value also in int.)

Thanks,
Mani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply bind the combo to an `ObservableCollection<int>` if you want 2 way db or `List<int>` for one way and retrieve the selected year by using SelectedItem

Comment: my bad, I missed to test the basics and started going through the value converter and stuff. It is pretty straight forward and binding any string or object. Thanks.